# Could not copy the file path\ApplicationInsights.config because it was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

just cloned a project from git on my new PC.
compile works fine (ctrl+shft+B), I have access to all source code.

when running the project (F5) i am getting this error:

"Could not copy the file path\ApplicationInsights.config because it was not found."

how can i get rid of this error ?

Comment: Same as me in UWP (You can add UPW tag maybe). Your answer did help.

Answer (score 10):

Answering my own question, the file was missing and all I had to do was to go to the source, right click on the ApplicationInsights.config file under the solution root and exclude from the project.

Comment: or someone didn't add the file to git in when they created the project?  the vs project knew about but it isn't in the file system when you pulled?

Comment: check the .gitignore file as it's likely to be included in there

Answer (score 4):

1. Right Click on project.
2. Open in file explorer.
3. Search for `ApplicationInsight.config` file.
4. Copy it.
5. Come back to visual studio and paste it into the project.